# mvn library issue

Tags: spring, maven, jar, mybatis

Hi i am doing mybatis with spring.

i used mybatis.jar and mysql-connector.jar as jars apart from spring jars.

i used maven repository for this.

with single spring i am able to run simple spring application(simple hello program)

But with adding mybatis.jar and connector.jar in mvn repository, it has not shown any compiler error.

when it is executed it is saying mybatis.jar and connector.jar errors.

so i included them in web-inf/lib folder then the program is working.

why it is not working with maven..have i done any mistake..

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

- Your project is not of type `war`,
- or the dependencies you mention do not have the correct `scope`; they should either have no scope, or `compile` scope – which is equivalent.

Comment: I got it.I haven't mentioned the dependencies for mybatis. Thank you very much